# How to configure minigui with qvfb?

Tags: qt

I just came across an issue with running minigui example.
I download qt-4.8.6 and install correctly on my Ubunut 14.04.
I can run qvfb without any problems, but when I want to run housekeeper (an example from minigui) something wrong happen:

```
start-qvfb :/opt/Qt-x11-4.8.6/bin/qvfb pcxvfb 3351 XVFB-for-MiniGUI-3.0-(Gtk-Version) 800x600-16bpp 
Unknown parameter 3351
Usage: pcxvfb [-width width] [-height height] [-depth depth] [-zoom zoom][-mmap] [-nocursor] [-qwsdisplay :id] [-x11display :id] [-skin skindirectory]
Supported depths: 1, 4, 8, 12, 15, 16, 18, 24, 32
NEWGAL>PCXVFB: Wait too long for CLIENT.
NEWGAL: Does not find matched engine: pc_xvfb.
KERNEL>InitGUI: Can not get graphics engine information!
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this annoying problem by using gvfb instead of qvfb,I download the gvfb v1.0 from http://www.minigui.org/en/download/.

Then:

tar -xzvf gvfb-1.0.0.tar.gz

cd gvfb-1.0.0

cmake .

In this step,you may come across :

`Linking C executable gvfb
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/gvfb.dir/gvfb_linux.o: undefined reference to symbol 'XkbGetIndicatorState'
//usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [src/gvfb] 错误 1
make[1]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/gvfb.dir/all] 错误 2
make: *** [all] 错误 2`

To solve this error:
you need to add **-lX11 -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXtst.a  -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.a** to gvfb-1.0.0/src/CMakeFiles/gvfb.dir/link.txt (Assume your host are 32-bit.)

then you can run make and make install.

You can run an example offered by minigui to test whether you have installed successfully or not !!!